"There is a bra for every ket, but there is not a ket for every bra"
This statement is an excerpt from Quantum Mechanics (Cohen-Tannoudji), but I don't quite understand why it holds: given all our kets live in a certain Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, then all the bras will live in the dual Hilbert space $\mathcal H^*$, and both of them will be equal in dimension and therefore they will be isomorphic. By definition, if they are isomorphic then there exists an isomorphism between the two spaces, which means for every ket there is one and only one bra, and viceversa. Nonetheless, this goes directly against the statement of the Cohen-Tannoudji, because an isomorphism is by definition surjective, whilst the aforementioned statement only requires injectivity and actively rejects surjectivity. Why is my reasoning wrong? I'm thinking it might be failing because I'm using concepts of linear algebra specific for when the space has a finite dimension, but it makes no sense either because nothing is stopping a Hilbert space from having a finite dimension as well.

Suprajective? Do you mean surjective?

You might find the accepted answer of this MSE post helpful- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779194/what-is-bra-and-ket-notation-and-how-does-it-relate-to-hilbert-spaces

There's already an excellent answer and pointers, but to pick up on one thing: as a general rule the isomorphism between a vector space applies only if the spaces are finite dimensional. At some stage someone may have stated that rule without telling you they were assuming finite dimensionality and that's the core of where you went wrong.

@FrancisDavey Well, the Riesz representation theorem establishes a canonical (anti-)linear isomorphism between $H$ and its continuous dual $H^\prime$ even in the infinite-dimensional case.

@TobiasFünke - sure. But many books define the set of bra vectors as being elements of the algebraic dual (what I was taught to call the "dual"). Maybe that's unhelpful, but I think that's where the confusion comes from.

@FrancisDavey that's exactly what I've been taught as well, and books such as Cohen-Tannoudji treat bras as linear forms contained in the algebraic dual space of  $H$. Are you guys discussing there is another dual which isn't the algebraic one?

@Lagrangiano - yes. For infinite vector spaces, the algebraic dual (set of linear forms) will be much larger than the vector space. However, for Hilbert spaces you have more structure and can define not just linear but continuous maps. If you construct the space of continuous linear maps (the "continuous dual") the result is a much smaller space because being continuous restricts you. Authors are not consistent in which space bras live in.

The kets and bras do not always live in a Hilbert space, but when you write something like the "position eigenbras" $\langle x\rvert$, this lives in a larger space that is part of the Gel'fand triple of a rigged Hilbert space, see also this answer by user1504 for more details. Such a triple consists of a Hilbert space $H$, a subspace $S\subset H$ - and this subspace is not a Hilbert space, so its dual $S^\ast$ is not isomorphic via Riesz representation but we have a sequence of inclusions $S\subset H\subset S^\ast$. The bras live in $S^\ast$ and the kets in $S$ (not that most physics texts are careful about that, mind you, since they write both $\lvert x\rangle$ and $\langle x\rvert$ with abandon) and so there are, in this sense, "more" bras than kets.
